# Git: Error on pushing local repo unrelated histories error

Tags: git

1. So me and my colleague were working on a project everything was working fine.
2. We both were working on the same github repository.
3. Now he made some changes on his local copy and didnt commit and went on a vacation.
4. And i made 2-3 commits on master branch.
5. Now when he came he made commit on his local repo but is unable to push on remote repository.

How to merge the changes made by us so that no ones changes gets lost

Comment: first of all stash you college commit and pull all new changes and then pop the stash and try to push.

Comment: Ask your friend to pull the latest master and merge the master branch with his local branch where he made the changes using git merge master now he may face some merge conflicts.once the merge conflicts are fixed push the latest branch to git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git workflow with two developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755292/git-workflow-with-two-developers)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+two+developers

Answer (score 0):

Git is preventing your colleague from pushing their changes without your changes since that would lose your changes. Your colleague needs to `git pull --rebase` the changes from `origin/master` into their local master, then resolve any conflicts if they’re present, then `git push` so their changes are on top of your changes.